# Is there a way to easily validate entity association in Spring?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I am working on a Spring REST application where we have RequestMappings with nested path variables like so...

```kotlin
/grandparent/{grandparentId}/parent/{parentId}/child/{childId}
```

In my database there is a fk constraint from

```
child => parent

parent => grandparent
```

so a child knows its parentId and a parent knows its grandparentId

does Spring provide some easy way to validate that all of these are associated with one another?

If I had a request for

```kotlin
/grandparent/1/parent/2/child/3
```

I would want to ensure that child had a fk with parent and that parent had an fk with grandparent.

Ideally I'd like to abstract this away in the most elegant way possible and my intuition tells me there is a baked in way to handle this situation, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: good question; I am not aware of any; I would have introduced my own custom annotation for that.

Comment: If you structure your entities in the way described (child => parent, parent => grandparent) as embedded objects, I would expect BeanValidation based `@NotNull` check for parent/grandparent property to work just fine.

Am I getting it right, that you want to validate when reading the data?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt Not quite. The three path variables must all be related by database constraints. This way someone cannot provide a grandparentId and parentId that have no connection to a childId.

Comment: @codymikol before abstracting it, do you have a working draft/example that describes your case better?